# how to double filter a datagrid view in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to filter but it filter only onething i want to double filter

```
Dim DV As New DataView(dbDataSet)

Dim Db As New DataView(dbDataSet)
DV.RowFilter = String.Format("Class Like '{0}%'", ComboBox4.Text) = Db.RowFilter

Db.RowFilter = String.Format("Section Like '{0}%'", ComboBox5.Text)
DataGridView1.DataSource = Db
```

Comment: I think it might have worked if you'd connected one data view to the other, and not connected them both directly to the datatable but then used only one of them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called Boolean logic. You should learn about it. A filter is a Boolean expression. How do you usually combine multiple Boolean expressions? With `AND` and `OR` operators. Why should this be any different? A filter, in this context, is basically just a SQL `WHERE` clause.

Just bind your `DataTable` to the grid and then you can sort and filter via its `DefaultView`, which is where the data in the grid comes from:

```
myDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = $"Class LIKE '{ComboBox4.Text}%' AND Section LIKE '{ComboBox5.Text}%'"
```

Even better, bind your `DataTable` to a `BindingSource` and bind that to the grid, then set the `Filter` property of the `BindingSource`.

Comment: Dropping the first two sentences would improve this post

Answer (score 1):

Since I am not sure what `dbDataSet` is I would advise you that it must be a `DataTable`. If it is a `DataSet` then the constructor of the `DataView` should read `db.DataSet.Tables(0)`.

```
Private Sub OPCode2()
    Dim DV As New DataView(dbDataSet)
    DV.RowFilter = String.Format("Class Like '{0}%' And Section Like '{1}%'", ComboBox4.Text, ComboxBox5.Text)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = DV
End Sub
```

Comment: a DataSet can contain more than one table, so we cannot say for sure that it should be the 0th table